# How to get Android Google setting programatically?

Tags: android, security, settings, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-settings

In android 6.0 (marshmallow), there is `Google settings` in Android System Settings.

For example I want check if `Settings -> Google -> Nearby is on or off.

is it possible to get value of `Android Google settings` programmatically ?

If yes then how to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presently, there is no way to identify this option through pro-grammatically. I feel, Android developers has done it intentionally, as it cause serious safety issues for the user.